# Retrieving info from Azure Devops with Powershell

Tags: powershell, api, azure-devops

I'm trying to automate the deployment of releases in Azure Devops using the Azure Devops API with Powershell.  I'm able to retrieve the last release definition, but I'm not able to extract a release for a specific environment.

I'm looking to retrieve the last 'prod' release in order to obtain the 'release ID', and then deploy the release to UAT or DEV using a HTTP 'PATCH' request.

I can hit a URL manually (example below), which gives me the last release for DEV (definitionEnvironmentId=1), and I know I could easily changed the environment ID to '12' for production, but I'd like to get this via an API call.

https://{redacted url}/{redacted}/{redacted}/_apis/release/deployments?api-version=6.0&definitionId=1&definitionEnvironmentId=1&$top=1

Any ideas if this is possible as I can't find any info on it?

Comment: Looks like you might want to query the [`_apis/distributedtask/environments` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/environments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using the correct [Deployments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) Rest api. The reason you didnot get any info from the api call via powershell is because you didnot escape the special character `$` for `$top` parameter in the url.

`$` is a special character in powershell. You should escape it by adding a back tick '`' in the url. See below:

```
#add ` to $top parameter
$url = "https://{redacted url}/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=3&definitionEnvironmentId=5&`$top=1&api-version=6.0"

$connectionToken="PAT"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$response= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get

$releaseId = $response.value[0].release.id
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I went the long way about it by adding '$test = "$"+"top"+"=1"

       to then add it onto the end of the url, but adding the back tick you suggested works better.